# Energy and momentum operator on the interval

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Does there exists a common eigenbasis of the energy operator $T=p^2/2m$ and the momentum operator $p=-i\hbar\, d/dx$ for a particle in a 1-dimensional box of length $L$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer of if they exist lie in computing the commutator $[p^2, p]$, if it is zero then you can create such a basis

Comment: The commutator is zero. However, the eigenstates of T must be zero at the boundary of the box and the eigenstates of the momentum operatore can not vanish at the boundary!